# Please Help me. I am getting EOD tag Error while form processing in PHP

Tags: php

Please help me,

I am working on PHP form processing and i got this link

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3855686

After completing the tutorial getting the below errors.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/TestSub/public_html/form/contactformprocess.php on line 50

Here is my Code

```
    <?php 
$emailSubject = 'Contact Form';
$webMaster = 'Test@gmail.com';

$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$phoneField = $_POST['phone'];
$sexField = $_POST['sex'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$messageField = $_POST['message'];
$newsletterField = $_POST['newsletter'];    


$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $email <br>
Name: $name <br>
Phone Number : $phone <br>
Sex : $sex <br>
Country : $country <br>
Message : $message <br>
Newsletter : $newsletter <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .="Content-type:text/html\r\n";
$success = mail ($webMaster,$emailSubject,$body,$headers);

$theResults = <<<EOD

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Thank you For your intrest ! We will get back you very soon</h1>
</body>

</html>

EOD;
echo "$theResults";     

   ?>
```

Comment: Please provide us with your code.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: The above Tutorial from tutvid.com. i am using PHP EOD tag first time.

Comment: @shindedeepakm we know that. But you probably made an error somewhere. So please copy-paste your code in here or on Pastebin.com so we can have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no syntax error in your code. Are you sure that both of the

```
EOD;
```

Are placed at the beginning of their lines?

You can't have any tabs or spaces in front of it. This would give an error, since the ending tag for the heredoc declaration is not in the beginning of the line.

```
$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $email <br>
Name: $name <br>
Phone Number : $phone <br>
Sex : $sex <br>
Country : $country <br>
Message : $message <br>
Newsletter : $newsletter <br>
    EOD; // <-- this is wrong
EOD; // <-- this is right
```

Comment: Thank you all of you .Appreciate your reply . actually i have did for cleanness of the Code. i removed tabs from the EOD tag. but still am not getting any emails. Please help me. ?

Comment: Since you wrote "$webMaster = 'Test@gmail.com';", the email would be delivered to that email address. Otherwise your host might be blocking the "mail()" function. Check the result of the $success variable by putting "var_dump($success);" below the mail() function.

Comment: Thanks for reply .I have changed the Email ID with my ID. and uploaded to the server. after testing i am not getting mails. can you provide some alternate code for Form processing.it would be helpful.

Comment: After your Great Suggestion i have implemented var_dump($success) below mail function. So it ends up with "bool(false) ". pls can you help me with this.

Comment: That probably means your host doesn't allow e-mails to be sent. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496461/php-mail-function-returning-false-but-with-no-error.