# HTML Form Does Not Send

Tags: php, html, forms, email, smtp

please tell me how to fix this.

The HTML form gives the error message when submitting.

I just need this form to grab and send the info the user inputs to my email.

HTML

```
                     <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="assets/php/contact-form.php">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="text-center">Contact Us</legend>
                            <!-- Name input-->
                            <div class="form-group">                      
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>          
                            <!-- Email input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your email" class="form-control" required="required">
                                </div>
                            </div>          
                            <!-- Message body -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="How can we help?.." rows="5"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>          
                            <!-- Form actions -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                                    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-cyberdime">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

PHP - Here I'm using a fake email for this example to you, so don't worry about that. The issue is something else. I have no idea what it is. When someone tries to submit it just displays the error message echo "Error! Please try again."

```
<?php

$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

$to = "notmyactualemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Customer Attention Requested";
$message = " Name: " . $name  . "\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n Message: " . $message;


$from = "Website Contact Us Form";
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
  print "<script>document.location.href='http://mywebsite.com/thank-you.html';</script>";

}else{
  echo "Error! Please try again.";
}



?>
```

Comment: What error message? If it is a PHP error we need the PHP code.

Comment: show your php code also. And what error you are getting?

Comment: Did you put the `@` before the `mail` because you were getting an error, if so what was it? If not take that off and see if you get an error.

Comment: remove `@` from `mail()`  function and also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php` tag and see what error are coming.

Comment: are you tried what i said?

Comment: Yes, still get error. And no new errors display.

Comment: See this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496461/php-mail-function-returning-false-but-with-no-error