# Mail function doesn't work....I can't get the reason

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I made a PHP script for sending mail.....but I only get an "ERROR" message which is in the `else` condition...and I can't get mail.....that means my mail function doesn't work...

What could be the issue?

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$verify=$_POST['verify'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
exit();
}
if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
exit();
} else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
exit();
}
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


$to="contact@yoursite.com";

$subject='Inquiry';

$message='Name : '.$name."<br />".'Email : '.$email."<br />".'Mobile : '.$phone."<br />".'Message : '.$comments;

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

$mail=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if($mail) {
echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<div id='success_page'>";
echo "<h4>Email Sent Successfully</h4>";
echo "<p>Thank you $name, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</fieldset>";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: well - have you checked that your PHP is configured correctly and has an SMTP server to use for sending mail?

Answer (score 3):

It seems  mail function is returning false. mail function always return true or false. So you cant find out easily what went wrong if mail didnt work.It could be SMTP error, Connection Error or anything. Number of possibilities are there.
 [have a look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496461/php-mail-function-returning-false-but-with-no-error)

Comment: there is no SMTP error....its something different...may be scripting problem...plz solve this....site is live..

Comment: $checkmail = mail('example@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);

    if($check){ echo 'sent!';}
    else {print_r(error_get_last())};

Comment: Your Script is right.I think Problem lies within your server configuration.Please cross check once. Same code is working on my machine.

Comment: more sites and their mail functions are working fine on my server.....problem is only in this site mail function...

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Add this to your page and tell us the error

Comment: no any error on this

Comment: may be....my server only accept domain name email id....so when I have different mail id...like yahoo or gmail....what can I do to solve this ??

Comment: Does its say email sent and just not send the email?

Comment: only msg show is "ERROR"...which in an else part

Comment: Please Check the server's mail logs for more errors reported by server.

Answer (score 2):

This is the issue i assume.

```
if(!isEmail($email)) {}
```

IsEmail is not a fucntion unless you mean is_email which i think is wordpress?
or one i know of but you can use filter_var with filter_email

this would work too

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { //Return True Is Valid
echo "HEY IM VALID";
}
```

Also i would redo the if statement in some way like this

```
foreach ($_POST as $item => $value){
    if($value === ""){ echo $item." must be a valid input"; exit();}
 }
```

Comment: ok...bt its a validation issue...I want to solve mail issue....plz help me on that..

Comment: your mail structure is fine, and does send the email, might want to check your hosting, do they allow the mail function most free hosting blocks it but msg me up ill give ya a free account on my hosting server

Comment: else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
        exit();
   }

Make sure $_POST['verify'] = 4